# Sorting Firebase Realtime Database data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

[image]

I need to show these data in a table view, but they have been on the table view in mixing order. How can I put them in the same order as in the database. Please help, I will deeply appreciated.

First image shows my iPhone screen after running the project, second one is the database. I want them exact order as in the database.

Comment: Not clear how your data is sorted in Firebase DB — is it by *key/UID* or by *priority*?

Comment: Thank you for response, I have added the 2nd image to be more clear.

Comment: @muhcomen check my answer. If you have another questions - you are welcome

Comment: @muhcomen has it helped you?

Comment: Are you sure you want them displayed in the table in the same order shown in the screenshot? That's NOT the order it appears you wrote them to the database. i.e. period0, period1, period2 appears to be the order you wrote them, not period0, period1, period10...  The period10 is coming after period1 because they are sorted via ASCII sorting and showing in ASCII order, not the order you wrote them. If that's the case then the accepted answer won't work.

Comment: Thank you, when I enter the data, it is in order until 10, after 10, it is overlapping, I think because data is sorted by 1,11,111... That`s reason. Please if you have an idea, help me.

Comment: Have you tried the code in the accepted answer? It looks like it will give you the same result as it sorts the array by key. While it will give you the same results as in your screen shot, that's not really what you are after - you wanted them sorted period0, period1, period2...period10, right? If that's correct then please update your question as it's not asking the right thing and I will propose a solution.

Comment: Thank you, I want to be 1,2,3,....,11,12,13....

Comment: If the accepted answer solved the issue then you are set. If it didn't, then it should not be accepted so others will try to provide a solution that does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope periods objects look like this:

```
struct PeriodItem {
    let key: String

    let periodEnd: String
    let periodName: String
    let periodStart: String

    let ref: FIRDatabaseReference?

    init(periodEnd: String, periodName: String, periodStart: String, key: String = "") {
        self.key = key

        self.periodEnd = periodEnd
        self.periodName = periodName
        self.periodStart = periodStart

        self.ref = nil
    }

    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        key = snapshot.key

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        periodEnd = snapshotValue["periodEnd"] as! String
        periodName = snapshotValue["periodName"] as! String
        periodStart = snapshotValue["periodStart"] as! String

        ref = snapshot.ref
    }

    func toAnyObject() -> Any {
        return [
            "periodEnd": periodEnd,
            "periodName": periodName,
            "periodStart": periodStart,

            "key": key
        ]
    }
}
```

So

When you fill your array of `Periods` fully, just use sorting:

```
// periods - array of objects from firebase database
let yourTableViewPeriodsArray = periods.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key }) // maybe ">" instead of "<"
```

Then:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I call print([PeriodItem].self) in viewDidLoad I get Array<PeriodItem> instead of the actual array. Any ideas?